# How to show Nepali Numerical Unicode Characters in input field?

Tags: unicode, numbers, input-field

I think answer to this question might not be difficult but tricky obviously . I do not know why I cannot show the Nepali numbers in my application form. Though alphabetical Nepalese characters (क, ख, ग, etc) are displayed correctly, whenever I type or copy numbers typed in Nepalese unicode fonts it automatically gets converted to English.
For eg. **१२३४५६७८९०** are Nepalese unicode characters representing 1234567890. Could you please help what is being missed. For your reference I have pasted the link [here](http://202.45.146.140/v2/rab/public/register).

Comment: I do not why… Comment up (or remove) this line (26th one in my _reformatted_ local copy) `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">`.

Answer (score 0):

I am converting this from English Numbers to Nepali numbers using the following one-liner code. The output is in Nepali numbers. Other characters will not be affected.

If you use the "onkeyup" event for the field you could do the translation automatically.

```js
const toNe = n => n.replace(/\d/g, d => "०१२३४५६७८९"[d])

// Tests
console.log(toNe("The value is 12000"));
console.log(toNe("0123456789"));
console.log(toNe("यो संख्या 25000 हो"));
console.log(toNe("जन्म मिति 25 अक्टोबर 2010 हो"));
```